# Django Models Relationship Confusions

Tags: python, django

I have the following models:

```
class UserPost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class User(AbstractUser):
    MALE = 'M'
    FEMALE = 'F'
    GENDER_CHOICES = (
        (MALE, 'Male'),
        (FEMALE, 'Female')
    )
    posts = models.ManyToManyField(Post, through='UserPost')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

When I run python manage.py makemigrations, it raises the following error:

users.User.posts: (fields.E303) Reverse query name for 'User.posts' clashes with field name 'Post.user'.
        HINT: Rename field 'Post.user', or add/change a related_name argument to the definition for field 'User.posts'.

There is a many-to-many relationship between User and Post models. Each user can like many posts and each post can be liked by many users.
There is also a many-to-one relationship between User and Post models. Each user can write many posts and each post can be written by only one user.

Shouldn't reverse query name for 'User.posts' be user_set by default. If so, why is this name clashing with field name 'Post.user'? Can someone explain the meaning of this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the `UserPost` model? It looks to have all the same fields as `Post`, and if you're after efficient querying, [Django automatically creates database indexes on foreign keys](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey). Here's a simple setup that should work pretty well:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    # Your fields go here, but you might not need the posts field

class Post(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='posts')
```

This would let you do a `user.posts.all()` to get all of the `Post` instances that belong to that `user`.